# Im making a enemy behaviour script for my game in unity C# but there is a error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So this is the code:

```
var enemy = collision.collider.GetComponent<EnemyBehaviour>();
```

this is the error:

> The name 'collision' does not exist in current context

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Please post the whole script.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the compiler (the program that makes your code a program) can't locate `collision`.

This could mean, among other reasons, that you forgot to declare `collision` (so nowhere in your code did you write down `Collision collision`).

Probably you are trying to get `collision` outside of the following methods, which would be unusual and probably sits at the core of your issue:

```cs
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    ...
}

public void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    ...
}

public void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    ...
}
```